# How to deploy ERC721OrdersFeature (0x v4) for trade ERC20 - ERC721 on testnet

Tags: testnets, 0x

I want to integrate with 0x-protocol v4 for trading ERC20 Token <-> ERC721 Token, I think [ERC721OrdersFeature](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/contracts/zero-ex/contracts/src/features/nft_orders/ERC721OrdersFeature.sol) can help, how to deploy ERC721OrdersFeature smartcontract to BSC testnet?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to integrate ERC20<>ERC721 swap functionality into your app, the easiest way is using the NFT swap sdk built by one of our ecosystem partners (https://github.com/trader-xyz/nft-swap-sdk).

If you really need to deploy, the process is super straightforward. If you do plan to deploy it yourself, this [migration file](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/contracts/zero-ex/src/migration.ts) is what we use to deploy the Exchange Proxy + a subset of features in our tests; however, we don't promise support if you go this route.

Alternatively, if you are looking for a testnet, try ropsten  or forking bsc mainnet using hardhat (similar instructions for Ethereum mainnet: https://docs.0x.org/advanced-traders/guides/working-in-the-testnet#forking-mainnet-ethereum).